# Calculating time complexity for an algorithm by big oh notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Suppose time complexity of algorithm is `O(n^2)`.
Now I know that

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) , if c1*g(n)<=f(n)<=c2*g(n) for all n>=n0 

Constants c1 and c2 are positive real numbers
n0 = non negative integer    
f(n),g(n) = non negative functions of non negative arguments
```

Here `g(n) = n^2` and suppose `f(n) = n(n-1)`.I take `c1 = 0 and c2 = 1`.

So `0*(n^2) <= n(n-1) <= 1(n^2)`  where **`n>=1`**

But the condition is also satisfied by **`n>=0`**

But we generally don't have **`n = 0`**

So what do I write **`n>=0`** OR **`n>=1`**

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can write `n >= 12345` if you want. It just matters that there's some `n0` above which the inequality holds.

Comment: `n0 = non negative integer`, `for all n>=n0`, since `n0` is defined as non-negative, we shouldn't be concerned if it works for `n=0` or anything negative. Definetely `n>=1` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should read the statement is:

A function `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if after a certain point `n0` all the values of f(n) stay within a relative interval around g(n), between c1*g(n) and c2*g(n).

So you can say this about any relation as long as there exist a n0, c1 and c2. For this reason `n = 0` doesn't really matter. Nor does `n=1`. What matters is that after some point the condition holds. You can take `n0 = 42` show that the conditions hold and conclude that f(n)=n(n-1) is O(n^2).

For some more complicated functions `f(n)` will behave strangely for low values so it might make sense to just ignore them and pick some higher value. As long as you can find one such the conditions hold it's fine, regardless of how large `n0` is.

Comment: Got it.Also had a doubt that complexity of binary search is O(log n).So what is the base of log here.

Comment: @user3126632 Binary Search is O(logn), which is log base ten.  Binary Search actually runs in log n (base 2), but converting that to big-o is O(log n / log 2) which is O(log n).

Comment: @intboolstring Is time complexity same for iterative and recursive approach ?